# Editing CSV with duplicate entries, all matching are getting updated

Tags: c#, csv

I was asked to edit a csv file. While that in itself is no issue, the problem I am running into is if a part number exists more than once then all the data is being over written (for that same Part number). Specifically the last column which is the physical location of the part in the building.

I obviously am not seeing the solution. 15 columns of data per item. It's just the last column that is giving me trouble. If a part # 2N3055 exists in two or more locations, my code is over writing all instances of the location with what is entered from the textBox16.

```
    public void EditCSVPart2()
    {
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(","))
                    {
                        String[] split = line.Split(',');

                        if (split[0] == textBox2.Text && split[14] == textBox16.Text)
                        {
                            split[0] = textBox2.Text;
                            split[1] = textBox3.Text;
                            split[2] = textBox4.Text;
                            split[3] = textBox5.Text;
                            split[4] = textBox6.Text;
                            split[5] = textBox7.Text;
                            split[6] = textBox8.Text;
                            split[7] = textBox11.Text;
                            split[8] = textBox10.Text;
                            split[9] = textBox9.Text;
                            split[10] = textBox12.Text;
                            split[11] = textBox13.Text;
                            split[12] = textBox14.Text;
                            split[13] = textBox15.Text;
                            split[14] = textBox16.Text;

                            line = String.Join(",", split);
                        }
                    }
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
            {
                foreach (String line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        label3.Font.Size.Equals(12);
        label3.Text = "Update Complete!\nPress 'Return to Main Menu button.";
    }
```

Before Edit:

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     ACK Box 86

2N3055-5    SI  NPN     117     80  30   7  15  200   0.8       15      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055-6    SI  NPN     117     110 100  7  15  200   0.8       15      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055-7    SI  NPN     117     110 100  7  15  200   0.8       14      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055A SI  NPN     117     100 60   7  15  200   0.8       20      TO204       EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055E SI  NPN     115     100 60   7  15  200   2.5       20      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055F SI  NPN     115     100 60   7  15  200   2.5       20      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055G SI  NPN     115     100 60   7  15  200   2.5       20      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

2N3055H SI  NPN     115     100 60   7  15  200   0.8       20      TO3     EBC BJT     WEB

After Edit:

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

2N3055  SI  NPN     117     100 70   7  15  200   0.2       20      TO3     EBC BJT     300-2N3055-AA7

Comment: Rather than parsing the data manually, you would be better off using a tool like CSVHelper.  You would/could end up with a collection of objects which might make things easier to work with

Comment: CSVHelper is for .NET 4.5 & higher, I'm in .NET 4.0. But thank you trying to help.

Comment: You need to clarify “what” you are trying to do in the posted code. It looks very odd to “read” a csv line from the file, then split that line on commas, then “replace” those values in the split array with the values from the text boxes? Wouldn’t this mean that ALL the values would be the same since the values in the text boxes has NOT changed? Possibly show an example of what the line read contains and what you want to write back to the file.

Comment: I'm new to c#, self-taught. If a part number only exists only once, it works great as seen above. My issue is when there are variants on part numbers (2N3055, 2N3055A, etc). Then it changes all of the variants to the part number the user typed in. So I need help with how to treat if the part numbers have a variation (2N3055, 2N3055A, 2N3055-5, etc). A code example would help or point me do a microsoft doc. I have searched for code examples on the web, they all have the same issue when seeing duplicate part numbers.

Comment: I am not following… part number “2N3055” and “2N3055A” are two “different” strings so I do not see how the code would return `true` when checking if the two strings are equal. In other words, the posted code does not “update” the part number “2N3005A” if the given part number is “2N3005.” Can you show an example of this? I am just saying, that if what you say is happening, then it isn’t happening from the posted code… I have tested this.

Comment: @OldGuy1961-1 Have you tried stepping into it with the debugger? You'll be able to hover over the values in the variables and see if something is being set to a value that's unexpected.

Comment: Before Editing:  2N3055 SI NPN  117  100 70  7 15 200   0.2  20  TO3  EBC BJT  300-2N3055-AA7
2N3055 SI NPN  117  100 70  7 15 200   0.2  20  TO3  EBC BJT  ACK Box 86
2N3055-5 SI NPN  117  80 30  7 15 200   0.8  15  TO3  EBC BJT  WEB

Comment: I added the requested Before & After to above example.

Comment: Before - After? The before-after data does not look like a csv file. Where are the commas? The code is clearly using a comma for the delimiter, is there some reason it is missing in the posted before-after?

Comment: What is shown is from the screen output, the source files is a csv file.  private static readonly string file = @"c:\Datafile\Transistor.CSV"

Comment: Well, I am not sure how this helps… I do not see in the posted code where this is output. I am running the posted code and it would help to see the before-after csv file. In addition to what values are in `textBox2` and `textBox16`. I am unable to reproduce what you claim. The code works as expected from the before-after perspective of the csv file. Only the row with the matching data is updated, all other rows remain the same including variations of the part number. Are you sure the code you are running is the same code you have poster here?

Comment: @OldGuy1961-1:  The code you posted seems to work fine--although since you haven't posted the actual data from the CSV file, I re-created the comma-delimited data I used for testing using what you posted in "Before Edit". Some things to check: 1) Check that the data in the .csv file that you're reading in is still correct, 2) Check that the code where you print out the data "After Edit" is correct, 3) Check that you are actually calling "EditCSVPart2" and not some other method.

Comment: You may want to also double-check your assignments. For example, `split[7] = textBox11.Text;`. The statements previous to this were sequential `split[5] = textBox7.Text;`, then `split[6] = textBox8.Text;`. For `split[7]`, all of a sudden it jumps to `textBox11.Text`. From what I was seeing, I expected to see `split[7] = textBox9.Text;`

Comment: The data you posted there is not usable, since it's not in the actual format you're talking about; it's space separated, not comma separated. You should also really name those textboxes to the names of the actual data they contain, to make it easier to check whether everything gets assigned correctly.